# Strange execution time for summary query

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am giving here part of the query I am executing:

```
SELECT SUM(ParentTable.Field1),
       (SELECT SUM(ChildrenTable.Field1)
       FROM ChildrenRable INNER JOIN
           GrandChildrenTable ON ChildrenTable.Id = GrandChildrenTable.ChildrenTableId INNER JOIN
           AnotherTable ON GrandChildrenTable.AnotherTableId = AnotherTable.Id
       WHERE ChildrenTable.ParentBaleId = ParentTable.Id
       AND AnotherTable.Type=1),
       ----
FROM ParentTable
WHERE some_conditions
```

Relationships:

```
ParentTable -> ChildrenTable = 1-to-many
ChildrenTable -> GrandChildrenTable = 1-to-many
GrandChildrenTable -> AnotherTable = 1-to-1
```

I am executing this query three times, while changing only the Type condition, and here are the results:

Number of records that are returned:

```
Condition   Total execution time (ms)
Type = 1 :            973
Type = 2 :          78810
Type = 3 :         648318
```

If I execute just the inner join query, here is the count of joined records:

```
SELECT p.Type, COUNT(*)
FROM CycleActivities ca INNER JOIN
     CycleActivityProducts cap ON ca.Id = CAP.CycleActivityId INNER JOIN
 Products p ON cap.ProductId = p.Id
GROUP BY p.Type

Type 
---- -----------
1     55152
2     13401
4    102730
```

So, why would the query with Type = 1 condition execute much faster than the query with Type = 2, although it is querying 4x larger resultset (Type is tinyint)?

Answer (score 0):

The way your query is written instructs SQL Server to execute the sub-query with `JOIN` for every row of the output.

This way it should be faster, if I understand what you want correctly (UPDATED):

```
with cte_parent as (
   select 
      Id,
      SUM (ParentTable.Field1) as Parent_Sum
from ParentTable
group by Id
), 

cte_child as (
    SELECT
       Id,
       SUM (ChildrenTable.Field1) as as Child_Sum
    FROM ChildrenRable 
       INNER JOIN
           GrandChildrenTable ON ChildrenTable.Id = GrandChildrenTable.ChildrenTableId 
       INNER JOIN
           AnotherTable ON GrandChildrenTable.AnotherTableId = AnotherTable.Id
    WHERE 
           AnotherTable.Type=1
       AND
           some_conditions
    GROUP BY Id
)

select cte_parent.id, Parent_Sum, Child_Sum
from parent_cte 
join child_cte on parent_cte.id = child_cte.id
```

Comment: Hi Stoleg, you cannot group On ParentTable.Field1 like that, since it would multiply the result based on the number of joined records. The same applies for SUM(ChildrenTable.Field1. The only thing that would work correctly is if you did a SUM(GrandChildrenTable.Field1).

Comment: My guess is that you are interested in more than one row in your output, right? If so every row of output will be a summary for one (in simple case) attribute. What is the column you need numbers summed for? Or you need just a total of everything in 1 line?

Comment: It doesn't matter in what I am interested in, since the query you wrote is incorrect in any scenario. Let me be more precise: Lets say you have 1 record in ParentTable, with ParentTable.field1 = 200, and you have two records in ChildrenTable, each of them having one referenced record in GrandChildren table. When you execute a query that you wrote, SUM(ParentTbale.Field1) will return 2x200=400, and not 200, which is incorrect.